# formatting my output equation

Tags: c++, arrays

Trying to print out a polynomail i.e 10x^0+1*x^1 and 9*x^0+1*x^1 However the polynomials print out as

10x^0+1*x^1 +9*x^0+1*x^1, here is my for loop equation

```
 for(int i=0; i<=p->deg; i++) { 
     if (p->coeffs[i]==0)
       break; //dont want to print out any 0 constants

   cout << p->coeffs[i] <<" * " << x << "^"<<i << " ";

   if (p->coeffs[i]>0 && p->coeefs[i+1]!=0)
      cout<< "+";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if (p->coeffs[i]>0 && (i != p->deg) )
      cout<< "+";
```

Also, you shouldn't  `break` when `p->coeffs[i] == 0`, may be other coming coefficients are non-zero.

```
 if (p->coeffs[i]==0)
           continue; //dont want to print out any 0 constants
```

Also, so I think following *should* work

```
 for(int i=0; i< p->deg; i++) { //Notice only < sign
     if (p->coeffs[i]==0)
       continue; //dont want to print out any 0 constants

   cout << p->coeffs[i] <<" * " << x << "^"<<i << " ";

   if ( p->coeffs[i+1] > 0 )
        cout<< "+";
    }
```

Comment: @POW I used a test case of 1 2 3 and 1 -2 -3 and it printed out fine except for the second polynomial it printed out as 1*x^0 + -2*x^1-3x^2..Not sure how that extra + was printed since my condition states only values >0 can print the add symbol

Comment: @POW that actually ended up effecting the -3 now.. so it says +-3 instead of -3